# Atomikos config UserTransactionImp with UserTransactionServiceImp

Tags: spring, atomikos

I´m using Atomikos with Spring and I´m having problems to update the max_actives.

I´m creating the `UserTransactionImp`

```
<bean id="AtomikosUserTransaction" class="com.atomikos.icatch.jta.UserTransactionImp">
    <property name="transactionTimeout" value="300"/>
</bean>
```

But I would like to set `UserTransactionServiceImp` with the config of `max_actives`

```
<bean id="atomikosUserTransactionService" class="com.atomikos.icatch.config.UserTransactionServiceImp"
      init-method="init" destroy-method="shutdownForce">
    <constructor-arg>
        <props>
            <prop key="com.atomikos.icatch.service">com.atomikos.icatch.standalone.UserTransactionServiceFactory</prop>
            <prop key="com.atomikos.icatch.log_base_name">f2e_transactions</prop>
            <prop key="com.atomikos.icatch.output_dir">../standalone/log/</prop>
            <prop key="com.atomikos.icatch.log_base_dir">../standalone/log/</prop>
            <prop key="com.atomikos.icatch.max_actives">1000</prop>

        </props>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

The problem is that it´s seems like `UserTransactionImp` is creating an instance of `UserTransactionService` manually.

Any idea how to achieve this in Spring configuration?

```
 private void checkSetup() {
        Class var1 = TransactionManagerImp.class;
        synchronized(TransactionManagerImp.class) {
            this.txmgr_ = TransactionManagerImp.getTransactionManager();
            if (this.txmgr_ == null) {
                UserTransactionService uts = new UserTransactionServiceImp();
                uts.init();
                this.txmgr_ = TransactionManagerImp.getTransactionManager();
            }

        }
    }
```

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of configuring a UserTransactionServiceImp you can provide a file called transactions.properties at the root of the classpath as described here :

https://www.atomikos.com/Documentation/JtaProperties